# Adding margins to QML Layout

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to add padding/margins to my layout so my controls to appear so close to the border of the window. When i set the anchor margins it doesn't appear to actually affect anything.

[image]

[image]

This is the qml file displayed for the Settings Tab.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.2

Page {
    id: control

    title: qsTr("Settings")
    objectName: "SettingsView"


    ColumnLayout {
        spacing: 20

        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: parent.top

        Switch {
            text: qsTr("Theme")
            checked: root.Material.theme === Material.Dark
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            LayoutMirroring.enabled: true

            onClicked: {
                root.Material.theme = checked ? Material.Dark : Material.Ligth
                //Settings.currentTheme = root.Material.theme
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 500

    // Theme
    Material.theme: Material.Dark
    Material.accent: "#4096DD"
    Material.primary: "#4096DD"

    // Controls
    header: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex
        TabButton {
            //text: qsTr("Home")
            icon.source: "qrc:/Images/home.svg"
        }
        TabButton {
            //text: qsTr("Settings")
            icon.source: "qrc:/Images/settings.svg"
        }
    }

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

        Page1 {
        }

        SettingsView {

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an Item is affected by a Layout then you must use Layout.margins if you want to set all the margins to the same value, but if you want to set a different margin in each direction you must use Layout.leftMargin, Layout.topMargin, Layout.rightMargin and Layout .bottomMargin, in your case:

```
ColumnLayout {
    spacing: 20

    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.top: parent.top

    Switch {
        Layout.leftMargin: 20
        Layout.topMargin: 20
        Layout.rightMargin: 20
        // ...
```

**Update:**

Then set the margin at the anchor:

```
ColumnLayout {
    spacing: 20

    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.top: parent.top

    anchors.leftMargin: 20
    anchors.topMargin: 20
    anchors.rightMargin: 20

    Switch {
        text: qsTr("Theme")
        // ...
```

Comment: I want margins on the entire ColumnLayout, not just my Switch control. Because ill be adding more controls and i want them all to be padded from the edge of the window.

Comment: @JokerMartini FYI, some items have internal margins other than 0, so if it is not aligned consider considering those margins to 0.

Comment: hmmm appears to also have no affect on anything.